# Obtaining max values for each day in the past 28 days

Tags: mysql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I've seen some of the past posts where there were questions about extracting max values for each day. Based on this, I tried `SELECT ts, MAX(current) FROM mytable WHERE ts > date_add(now(), interval -28 day);` but I only got one row back which is not what I want.

In this table, `ts` is my timestamp and `current` is another column of values. I want to get the max `current` values for each day in the past 28 days. However, my `current` values are recorded into the table every 30 mins each day. Therefore, there are many `ts` values for each day. Could this be the reason why the above query design doesnt work? If so, how can I amend it?

Here is an example of how my table look like for a few rows:

```
+---------------------+--------------+
| ts                  | current |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2018-01-20 16:27:10 |       439.37 |
| 2018-01-20 17:00:18 |       378.07 |
| 2018-01-20 17:30:15 |       204.80 |
| 2018-01-20 18:00:16 |       196.50 |
| 2018-01-20 18:30:16 |       179.40 |
| 2018-01-20 19:00:16 |       183.00 |
| 2018-01-20 19:30:16 |       105.00 |
```

Comment: `SELECT date(ts), MAX(current) FROM mytable WHERE ts > date_add(now(), interval -28 day) GROUP BY date(ts)`

Comment: Thanks! That works! The `date(ts)` is used to convert the timestamp to date format only I suppose?

Comment: Yes. Though I'd say it *extracts* the date part from a timestamp. But the most important change is the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: the date_add bit isn't really necessary (or rather, it's implied, whether you write it or not). So `ts > curdate() - interval 28 day` will suffice

Comment: See groupwise-max